# Any suggestion for Ruby on Rails multilingual translation management?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, translation, multilingual

I am developing a Ruby on Rails application with multilingual support. Now I have 4 languages, each have a separate yml file. I found this is inconvenience that when I add a new translation, I need to add all the lines manually to each yml file.

Does any good translation management tools can help me on this?

Thanks everyone. :)

Comment: Did you end up going with Translate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using [Translate](https://github.com/mynewsdesk/translate/) to edit YML files.

Comment: Thanks! it is simple enough and function well. :)

Answer (score 9):

Here are some links that I've gathered

Free (gems)

- https://github.com/firmafon/iye IYE makes it easy to translate your Rails I18N files and keeps them up to date
- https://github.com/tolk/tolk Tolk is a web interface for doing i18n
  translations packaged as an engine for Rails 4 applications
- https://github.com/local-ch/i18n-docs Maintain translations in Google
  Docs and export them to your Rails project.
- https://github.com/mynewsdesk/translate A Ruby on Rails plugin with a
  web interface for translating I18n texts
- https://github.com/mose/rails-i18nterface A rails 3/4 engine based
  interface for translating and writing translation files
- https://github.com/fourmach/i18n_dashboard Rails Engine for I18n
  management with redis as backend
- https://github.com/grosser/fast_gettext Ruby GetText, but 3.5x faster
  ...   https://github.com/copycopter/copycopter-server /
- http://copycopter.com Copycopter Server is open source. Run it as a
  web service.
- https://github.com/nijel/weblate / http://weblate.org/
  / Web based translation tool with tight Git integration.

Paid (apps)

- http://www.tr8nhub.com/pricing (starting free - https://github.com/tr8n/tr8n)
- https://www.localeapp.com/pricing (24€/month)
- https://translationexchange.com/pricing ($39/month)
- https://phraseapp.com/ ($9/month /language/project)

  - more advices http://eng.joingrouper.com/blog/2014/04/03/rails-internationalization-translation/
- http://www.smartling.com/product (Contact Sales - complex)

Comment: I've actually ended up by forking and improving https://github.com/local-ch/i18n-docs in https://github.com/AntoineInsa/i18n-docs

Answer (score 2):

Tolk can help you to do that: http://github.com/tolk/tolk

Comment: Thanks mate. I can't use it becoz it just support one kind of Chinese character. Thanks anyway. :)

Comment: I tried using tolk with rails 3 but it is too out of date and has too many open issues.

Comment: note that tolk has many forks, some are up to date for latest rails

Answer (score 2):

Personally I'm using http://99translations.com/ Easy to use for non-programmers, eg. translators and free for the open source projects.

Another service https://webtranslateit.com/ is growing and in active development (blog is updating frequently). They have also free plan, on which you can store up to 500 strings, even for non open source project.

Both have API, for which they have rake task to update translations on your local machine and also on their server. Actually never used, but I think it's good when you have > than 1000 strings and updates are frequent.

Answer (score 0):

There's https://github.com/berk/tr8n but it looks pretty hard core and it focuses more on the front end crowdsourcing component.